# Signal Processing Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

> **Note:** The email that went out mentioned Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange - this was an error. The title did not get edited from the last swag email that went out. All the other information in the email, including the closing date for the form, is correct. This is swag for Signal Processing. Sorry about the confusion.

We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

[image: A T-SHIRT!]

T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!

[image: STICKERS!]

STICKERS!!!!!!!

I'll be reaching out to you shortly with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

**Update 02/14/2017:** This is currently in the proofing process. Once the proofs are approved and finalized by our designers, the warehouse will begin printing and shipping. This delay is partially my fault here - the holidays caused this to get lost for over a month.

Comment: Cool swags ! Btw, my message reads: *"...the top users in Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange..."* while the link sends to DSP.SE,  am I the only one with the electrical part ?

Comment: @Gilles No, sorry. I got the email title right but forgot to edit the title in the email itself. :P Totally my bad.

Comment: @Gilles Same for me. I should tell my former EE teachers. They'll have a seizure...

Comment: Please, do not sent me an " Electrical Engineering" t-shirt. I would not be able to wear it in public:)

Comment: @animuson Hi there, I have not received anything and would definitely be interested in this :) Thank you very much for doing it anyway. How can we go about communicating regarding postal address etc?

Comment: @animuson Any update on this?

Comment: @A_A Sorry, I guess I missed your initial comment somehow. I looked and you were on the list of recipients for the email. Would you be able to email me (my display name @stackoverflow.com) and I'll send you a link to the form manually.

Comment: @animuson No worries, thank you for your message, I have responded via email.

Comment: I was indeed worried the postman could have stole it. Glad to know the preprint is on its way

Comment: @LaurentDuval , I thought the same here:). But they're coming !

Comment: @Gilles mine just arrived!

Comment: @LaurentDuval mine just arrived!

Comment: @PeterK.  I'm still waiting for mine :(

Comment: Hope is on its way

Comment: I received mine. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, got them today!

Comment: Got it! Thank you guys!

Comment: Me too. Good suprise

Comment: YAY ! I just got it today :D

Comment: Woo-hoo! Good to see the good guys getting some swag. :-)

Comment: I tend to buy clothes in bulk, so that I can keep the same look everyday. This DSP T-shirt has add some success in my surroundings. Can I buy its siblings?

Answer (score 2):

I am a living proof (so far so good) of the capture of one realization of the top user swag process. Still trying to infer the probability density function of this process on one sample: I am not a Bayesian.

[image: DSP StackExchange Tshirt]

Comment: Well you can be sure that the probability is non-zero!

Comment: That is the h... of a useful prior for  pdf!